# Replace content of a tag using RegEx

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I want to match all the words that end with “!” from this tag:

`<div>Why I love! you so much</div>`

In this case, I want to match the word love! because has an `!`

Now, I made this beautiful regex:

`(?-s)(<div>)*\w+!(?!\w*;)(?=[^<]*</div>)`

After replace, My tag should look like this:

`<div>Why I love you so much</div>`

So, I want to use this regex, to replace in several .html files all those tags that has `!` Basicaly, I want to delete them from these tag. I try to replace ! wih an empty space, like so:

Search: `(?-s)(<div>)*\w+!(?!\w*;)(?=[^<]*</div>)`

Replace by: `\1\2(LEAVE EMPTY)`

But doesn’t work. Can anyone help me?

Basicaly, I want to delete all `!` which sticks to words from these tag, from several files.

Comment: What language is at your service?

Comment: Use this instead: `(?-s)(?:<div>)*\w+(!)(?!\w*;)(?=[^<]*<\/div>)` It'll only catch the `!`, and not the `<div>` part

Comment: Is "!" contained only once in each tag or can they be more than one?

Comment: can be more than one :)

Comment: So "<div>Why I love! you so! much</div>" should be replaced into "<div>Why I you much</div>" removing "love" and "so" ?? and it can be any tag, not just div, right?

Comment: both answers are corect :) done. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(<([^>]+)>[^>]*?[ ]\w+?)\!([^>]*?<\/\2>)
```

replaced by

```
\1\3
```

Then

```
This is not! in tag.

<div>Why I love! you so! much </div> This is not! in tag. <div>Why I love! you so! much </div>
```

this will be replaced into

```
This is not! in tag.

<div>Why I love you so! much </div>  This is not! in tag. <div>Why I love! you so! much </div>
```

removing first ! in the `<div>` tag.

There is no way to do it at once to remove ! from `love!` and `so!` in the example above in Notepad++ as it can process only once in same line so unfortunately you have to continue replacing until you don't find anymore. but you can write Python script to do it. Then it will be one click to do all the file or even all files in a folder so worth to write, or more advanced text editor like Vim :) if you write a script, you can specify if you want to process the same repeatedly or just once into the same line/string so you can do a lot more things easil.

About the regex,
`<([^>]+)>` is representing `</div>` in the example, `[^>]+` means "anything except `>`". So this prevents `<AAA><BBB>` gets `AAA><BBB` as the match instead `AAA` because regex chooses longer match otherwise. So `<([^>]+)>` is a general way to write HTML tag, it can match a long HTML tag like `<a href=....>` too.

Comment: hello haruka. It doesn't work your regex. Basicaly, I want to delete all `!`  which sticks to words from thise tags. I can search and find every words, but I don't know how to delete those `!` :)

Comment: Do you want to delete only ! but not the words?? You have to write a script if you are trying to delete all !, because Notepad++ can process only once in one line. so you have to click replace button until there is no more ! if you can't write a script.

Comment: SUPER !! Thanks. Please put your last 2 response on Answer, so as to vote and accept it.

Comment: and Haruka, if you mention it, can you make a regex to replace all `love!` with `love !` ? means, to add a space before `!` for all words in tags? And "!" is contained only once in each tag .

Comment: `(<([^>]+)>[^>]*?[ ]\w+?)(\![^>]*?<\/\2>)` then replace by `\1 \3`. Try to learn Python scripting, you can do so much more things ;)

Comment: thanks a lot ! works splendid ! put this on answer, too. And please give me a good tutorial to learn phyton, if you kno some :)

Comment: @RobRob No need to [learn Python](https://www.learnpython.org/en/) to solve *this* task, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602195/3832970) showing how to use NPP Boost regex to do it with a single click, but it is certainly a good idea to learn more languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `!` that are glued to the end of words with a pure regex and a single search and replace button click:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<div>)[^<]*?\K\b!\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHbD4u/1). To insert a space between the word and `!`, just replace with  `!`.

**Pattern details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<div>)` - a `<div>` substring (`<div>`) or (`|`) the end of the last successful match (`\G(?!^)`)
- `[^<]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `<`, as few as possible since `*?` is a lazy quantifier
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding all text matched so far from the match buffer
- `\b` - a word boundary (immediately before the `!`, there should be a word char)
- `!` - a `!`
- `\B` - non-word boundary (immediately after the `!`, there should be a non-word char or end of string).